# Change more then one variable in one line?

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I have this

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;
const int v = 50;

//change x,y,z
x += v;
y += v;
z += v;
```

Its fine, but is there a shorter way to avoid this 3 lines of code (with `+=`) and have only one? I just asking myself, because I have to add some const to these variables very often and then I have to add always +3 lines (or more if I would have xyz+ variables).

Comment: If you're adding a constant to these variables often, why not put it in a private method and just call the method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is going to happen very often, you might want to put these in a class. For example, if these are locations within a virtual page:

```
class PageLoc
{
    public int Header { get; set; }
    public int Body { get; set; }
    public int Footer { get; set; }

    void MoveAll(int distance) {
        Header += distance;
        Body += distance;
        Footer += distance;
    }
}
```

That way, you can change their values independently or collectively.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a method to increment all three variables and pass the variables by reference:

```
Add(ref x, ref y, ref z, 50);
```

with

```
void Add(ref int x, ref int y, ref int z, int v)
{
    x += v;
    y += v;
    z += v;
}
```

Comment: _The cure is worse than the disease!_ but still a valid answer.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the x,y,z into a class and write a method to add a constant to all three:

```
class XYZ
{
  public void Add (int v) { x += v; y += v; z += v; }
  int x,y,x;
}
```

Some code to use above:

```
void F ()
{
  XYZ xyz;

  xyz.Add (3);
}
```

Of course, you can improve the above by overloading the += operator as well as the other operators. In effect, you've created a vector and there's libraries available that already implement this (maybe in DirectX).

Answer (score 1):

```
z += 0 * (y += 0 * (x += v) + v) + v;
```

Tadah :D

**But I don't recommend using this!** Of course the better way is to create a method that does that. That would also give you only one line (+ a method declaration).

Comment: I just vomited a little. :) But I applaud your effort to answer exactly what the OP was asking.

Comment: @Ryan Always at the OP's service! :D Of course this is very bad practive, thats why I advised against it and gave an alternative. ^^